# Cypress how to temporarily escape from a cy.within()

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am working to write auto tester code on cypress.
As web app is vue.js project, page consists of component in src.
So in cypress, I decide to scope all subsequent commands to within component root instead of document root(html).
So that cy.get or cy.find will query within component root dom.

But I often need to query some elements outside current scoped component.
for example: when I have custom select that renders dropdown outside component, in cypress, inside cy.within there is no way to select dropdown option because it is rendered outside component root.

So I tried to escape scope temporarily to select dropdown and then come back into scope again for next commands.

```js
cy.get(".account-mortgage-component form").within(() => {
  cy.get("input[name='postcode']").type("ng2 6dg").blur();
  
  // click input.select-address to open dropdown
  cy.get("input.select-address").click();
  
  // then dropdown is rendered outside .account-mortgage-component. so next command can not work
  cy.get(".select-address-dropdown").contains("3 Carnarvon Road, West Bridgford").click();
  
  // I hope to escape current scope, so make above code to work. after this I should come back to scope again for next commands.
  
  cy.root().submit();
});
```

```html
<div class="account-mortgage-component">
  <form>
    <input name="postcode" />
    <div class="custom-select">
      <input class="select-address" />
    </div>
  </form>
<div>

<div class="select-address-dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>3 Carnarvon Road, West Bridgford</li>
    <li>5 Carnarvon Road, West Bridgford</li>
    <li>6 Carnarvon Road, West Bridgford</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As my web project is big scaled already, in cypress I should scope most commands using cy.within.
Any solution will be help.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6666

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`cy.document().its('body')` will give you a subject that is outside the `.within()`, and it seems to go back to inner scope after (still within callback).

```js
cy.get('body').find('div.without');  // checking this query first (outer scope)

cy.get('div.myform').within(() => {

  cy.contains('text within');                      // inner scope

  cy.document().its('body').find('div.without');   // outer scope

  cy.contains('text within');                      // inner scope
})
```

Tested with this html

```html
<body>
  <div class="myform">
    <div>text within</div>
  </div>
  <div class="without">text without</div>
</body>
```

---

### Nested withins

You can nest `.within()` statements using the same breakout pattern,

```js
cy.get('div.scope1')
  .within(() => {
    cy.contains('text within scope1');            // testing in scope1
    cy.document().its('body').find('div.scope2')
      .within(() => {
        cy.contains('text within scope2');        // switch to scope2
      })
    cy.contains('text within scope1');            // back to scope1
  })
```

Tested with this html

```html
<body>
  <div class="scope1">
    <div>text within scope1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="scope2">
    <div>text within scope2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, nested .within is working well, I tested enough.

Comment: Cool, it works pretty well to use nested within.
The way to within any element (can be parent) from one within is really innovation.
I see It may be new way to discovery something.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cy.document()` to yield the `window.document` object and then use `within` to scope all subsequent requests within your function to the document.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="subject"]').within(($subject) => {

  // Here cy commands are scoped within your subject

  cy.document().within(($document) => {

    // Now cy commands are scoped within the document

  });

  // Here cy commands are again scoped within your subject

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alias and then call it with the **@** handle:

```
cy.get(".select-address-dropdown").as('select-address-dropdown')
  
  cy.get(".account-mortgage-component form").within(() => {
    cy.get("input[name='postcode']").type("ng2 6dg").blur();
    
    // click input.select-address to open dropdown
    cy.get("input.select-address").click();
    
    // Here you can reference the select alias:
    cy.get("@select-address-dropdown").contains("3 Carnarvon Road, West Bridgford").click();
    
    // I hope to escape current scope, so make above code to work. after this I should come back to scope again for next commands.
    
    cy.root().submit();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but what I want is to escape scope.
As I told in question description, most commands are scoped, so it's really pain to use alias for all potential elements outside. If I can escape scope to query any element outside. And I am not sure this code is working properly.
.select-address-dropdown does not exist initially, it is rendered only when to click .select-address.

Answer (score 1):

```js
cy.get('body').find('div.without');  // checking this query first (outer scope)

cy.get('div.myform').within(() => {

  cy.contains('text within');                      // inner scope
  
  // This is very important.
  cy.wrap(Cypress.$('html')).find('div.without');   // outer scope

  cy.contains('text within');                      // inner scope
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="myform">
    <div>text within</div>
  </div>
  <div class="without">text without</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`cy.document().its('body')` didn't work for me for some reason, maybe due to retryability

Cypress 12:

`Cypress.Commands.addQuery('escapeWithin', () => () => cy.$$('body'))`

`cy.escapeWithin().find('div.without')`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).