# Cypress: cannot find elements in calendar popup

Tags: angularjs, cypress, owl-date-time

I cannot interact with the date picker (popup) in my Cypress tests.

I tried .find() and .get() on every div class but each time it says
`Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: .cdk-overlay-container, but never found it`

This is my test code:

```
      cy.get('#signup-step-pers-details').within(() => {
        cy.get('[name="firstName"]').type(user.firstName)
        .get('[name="surname"]').type(user.lastName)
        .get('#select-gender').click()
        .get('.ng-dropdown-panel-items').contains(user.gender, {matchCase: false}).click()
        .get('#input-dateOfBirth').click()
        .find('.owl-dt-popup').click()
        .get('.owl-calendar-year').contains(2002).click()
```

I tried adding some wait time but that didn't help either.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your html dom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KKhan is correct, the Angular Date Time Picker opens in a `cdk-overlay-container` at the foot of the document.

More detail on the layout:

```html
<body>
  ...
  <div id="signup-step-pers-details>
    ...
    <div id="input-dateOfBirth"></div>
  </div>
  ...

  <div class="cdk-overlay-container">
    <owl-date-time-container>
      ...
    </owl-date-time-container>
  </div>

</body>
```

Using `cy.get('#signup-step-pers-details').within(() => {` restricts commands inside to that section of the DOM, but the `owl-date-time-container` is outside of that.

You can use this approach [Cypress how to temporarily escape from a cy.within()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928822/cypress-how-to-temporarily-escape-from-a-cy-within/65932605#65932605)

```
cy.get('#signup-step-pers-details').within(() => {

  // cy.root() === #signup-step-pers-details
  cy.get('[name="firstName"]').type(user.firstName)
    .get('[name="surname"]').type(user.lastName)
    .get('#select-gender').click()
    .get('.ng-dropdown-panel-items').contains(user.gender, {matchCase: false}).click()
    .get('#input-dateOfBirth').click()

  // shift cy.root() to date-time-picker
  cy.document().its('body').find('owl-date-time-container').within(() => {
    cy.get('button.owl-dt-control-period-button').click()
    cy.contains('2002').click()
    cy.contains('Aug').click()
    cy.contains('23').click()
  })

  // back to cy.root() === #signup-step-pers-details
  cy.get('#select-nationality').click()
})
```

**Note** I've used `.owl-dt-control-period-button` which is correct for the current version of Angular Date Time Picker, but perhaps you have an older version that requires `.owl-calendar-year`.

Answer (score 0):

This sequence

```js
.get('#input-dateOfBirth').click()
.find('.owl-dt-popup').click()
```

is expecting to find the date popup *within* the dateOfBirth control.

You may simply need

```js
.get('#input-dateOfBirth').click()
.get('.owl-dt-popup').click()
```

Generally you see `cy.get()` for each item, not chaining all the gets as you have done. That still works because `.get()` always starts it's search at `cy.root()`, which is set to `#signup-step-pers-details` by the `.within()`.

But the `.find()` is different, it starts it's search at the previous subject, which is the DOB control.

I should add, in case you were expecting the date popup to actually be inside the DOB input, that `cdk-overlay-container` is added when the popup is made visible, at the bottom of the `<body></body>` tag (take a look in devtools).

```html
  <div class="cdk-overlay-container">...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sadly I had also tried using get, and cy.get. But neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using `contains` is good but there is [another syntax](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Selector) you may use for the purpose of selecting a date:

```
      cy.get('#signup-step-pers-details').within(() => {
        cy.get('[name="firstName"]').type(user.firstName)
        .get('[name="surname"]').type(user.lastName)
        .get('#select-gender').click()
        .get('.ng-dropdown-panel-items').contains(user.gender, {matchCase: false}).click()
        .get('#input-dateOfBirth').click()
        .find('.owl-dt-popup').click()
        .contains('.owl-calendar-year', '2002').click()
```